# Carrierwave gem Video upload and thumbnail generation with rotation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave gem to upload video recorded from iPhone and create thumbnails of video uploaded using [carrierwave-video-thumbnailer gem](https://github.com/evrone/carrierwave-video-thumbnailer).

Now I am facing issue with rotating thumbnail image that was generated by carrierwave-video-thumbnailer gem. I need to rotate to portrait based on video orientation.

Please see my VideoUploader class below.

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Video
  include CarrierWave::Video::Thumbnailer

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process thumbnail: [{format: 'jpg', quality: 7, size: 640, strip: false, logger: Rails.logger}]
    def full_filename for_file
      png_name for_file, version_name
    end
    process :set_content_type_jpg
  end

  def png_name for_file, version_name
    %Q{#{version_name}_#{for_file.chomp(File.extname(for_file))}.jpg}
  end

  def set_content_type_jpg(*args)
    Rails.logger.debug "#{file.content_type}"
    self.file.instance_variable_set(:@content_type, "image/jpeg")
  end
end
```

Comment: Does this gem still work?  It hasn't been updated in a few years.

Answer (score 0):

You should include:

```
include CarrierWave::RMagick
```

and based on [this](http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/RMagick.html)

```
process :do_stuff

def do_stuff(blur_factor)
  manipulate! do |img|
    img = img.auto_orient
    # or something similar
  end
end
```

Full list of operations with RMagick can be found [here](https://rmagick.github.io/optequiv.html).

Comment: I tried this but I get ` ["Failed to manipulate with rmagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: delegate failed `\"ffmpeg\" -v -1 -mbd rd -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 300 -i \"%M%%d.jpg\" \"%u.%m\" 2> \"%Z\"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1065"]}> `

Here code trying to take MP4 as input.